Crash occurs and the application closes when writing a pdf file by using itext library version 7.1.17
I apologize to everyone, as I do not have a computer, so I cannot use Android Studio and find out the exceptions .
my problem is Crash occurs and the application closes when writing a pdf file by using itext library version 7.1.17
and i added all permissions
i checked the storage and found a blank PDF file
At first I thought the problem was due to the font type. I used the fonts integrated with the library and it did not solve the problem. I tried other versions and it did not solve the problem either
this is dependencies
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.2.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:kernel:7.1.17'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:layout:7.1.17'
    implementation 'com.itextpdf:io:7.1.17'
}

and this is my simple code
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
        } else {
        pdfWriter();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            pdfWriter();
            } else {
            System.out.println("Permission Denied!");
        }
    }
}

public void pdfWriter() {
    PdfWriter writer = null;
    PdfDocument pdf = null;
    Document document = null;
    
    try {
        
        String pdfPath = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/invoice.pdf";
        
        
        writer = new PdfWriter(pdfPath);
        pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        document = new Document(pdf);
        
        
        document.add(new Paragraph("Sales Invoice")
        .setFontSize(18)
        .setBold()
        .setMarginBottom(20));
        
        
        document.add(new Paragraph("Seller: ABC Store\nAddress: Main Street, City\nPhone: 123456789")
        .setFontSize(12)
        .setMarginBottom(10));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Customer: John Smith\nAddress: Future District, City\nPhone: 987654321")
        .setFontSize(12)
        .setMarginBottom(20));
        
        
        float[] columnWidths = {50, 200, 100, 100};
        Table table = new Table(columnWidths);
        
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("No.").setBold()));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Product").setBold()));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Quantity").setBold()));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Price").setBold()));
        
        
        String[][] products = {
            {"1", "Laptop", "2", "$1500"},
            {"2", "Smartphone", "1", "$1200"},
            {"3", "Keyboard", "3", "$100"}
        };
        
        for (String[] product : products) {
            for (String data : product) {
                table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(data)));
            }
        }
        
        
        document.add(table);
        
        
        document.add(new Paragraph("Total Amount: $4400")
        .setFontSize(14)
        .setBold()
        .setMarginTop(20));
        
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
        
        if (document != null) {
            document.close();
        }
    }
}

}`
I then thought about using another library, which is PDFBox, and there was a conflict between the libraries and it was a more terrible problem. I searched for built-in libraries and found that they do not support watermarks and passwords.
I finally got access to the records and this is what they show
ERROR:  Failed to perform rewrite, java.lang.RuntimeException: Rewrite cancelled.
    at com.tyron.completion.util.RewriteUtil.lambda$performRewrite$0(RewriteUtil.java:33)
    at com.tyron.completion.util.RewriteUtil$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.call(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleAsyncTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:167)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleAsyncTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:150)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

ERROR:  Failed to perform rewrite, java.lang.RuntimeException: Rewrite cancelled.
    at com.tyron.completion.util.RewriteUtil.lambda$performRewrite$0(RewriteUtil.java:33)
    at com.tyron.completion.util.RewriteUtil$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.call(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleAsyncTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:167)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleAsyncTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:150)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)


Use Logcat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. If you do not understand what the stack trace is telling you, please edit your question and post the entire stack trace.

I don't have a computer so I can't use Android Studio and find out the problems

Implement something like Crashlytics or ARCA may be to log the crash without the need for a computer. Also did you try the standard PDFBox or the Android port of it ( https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android ) as I'm not aware of any library problems with the port, only with the standard version.

I tried the library you talked about and it also crashed. I think there is a missing part of the code or permissions. I don’t really know. Could one of you copy the code and try it to check for exceptions?

There are so many different version of Android and permissions have changed a lot you really need to specify which Android Versions is it crashing on. I also avoid doing anything with itext due to it's licensing requirements.

How are you programming without a computer?

But its likely is that as you have not checked the state of Environment.getExternalStorageState(File) then location of this might be on is not mounted as it could be on an external SD card.

You don't really give enough info but try adding the following as you should always check the state of External Storage.

String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
     String pdfPath = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/invoice.pdf";
     ...

} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "External Storage not mounted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


Update
The other source of possible errors is you don't check if the file already exists and is Writeable or possibly for some reason you app is not the owning app of this directory (Duplicate App ID as you might be doing things with an on Android code IDE)

I thank everyone for the help and patience with me. I tried a lot and found that this is the problem. Perhaps it is because of my development environment. I finally checked the logs and this appeared to me ,I modified my question to show the logs

I tried this library github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android It did not work either, despite powerful libraries that were working perfectly on the same environment. I don’t know why pdf libraries not working
